# How to Add UIViewController from UVIew with orientation management

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, orientation, mpmovieplayercontroller

I'm creating my custom MPMoviePlayer.

For full screen management, the `MPMoviePlayerController` behaves this way :

```
- (void)setFullscreen:(BOOL)fullscreen animated:(BOOL)animated;
```

I would like to do the same, but with an `UIViewController` added over all `UIView`.
But when using a `UIViewController`, the orientation is not managed

My currently code :

```
AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
[[appDelegate window] addSubview:myViewController.view];
```

I'd like to manage the orientation using an `UIViewController`.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes I Can !

My ViewController "myViewController" is added over all views with orientation management :

```
AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
UIViewController *rootViewController = appDelegate.window.rootViewController;
[rootViewController presentViewController:myViewController animated:NO completion:nil];
```

Answer (score 1):

When using `setFullscreen:YES...` on that `MPMoviePlayerController` instance, it will stop using the view stack that you supplied and instead use its own (directly on a window).

In other words;

`MPMoviePlayerController`'s `view` **instance does not consistantly stick to the supplied parent view once it is switched to fullscreen mode**. It only does so when using non fullscreen mode.

To work around that feature, you will need to implement your own means of switching between fullscreen and embedded mode. Sounds major but in fact is rather trivial.

Simply create a method within your viewController that looks something like this.

The following assumes:

- your viewController handles the entire screen
- your viewController has a property (typed `CGRect`) that contains the embedded metrics
- your `MPMoviePlayerController` instance within that viewController is
  called `player`

I skipped any possible animations for you to implement yourself. You may also switch the control style within this method to mimic the original behaviour.

```
- (void)setFullscreen:(BOOL)fullscreen
{
    if (fullscreen)
    {
        self.player.view.frame = self.view.bounds;
    }
    else
    {
        self.player.view.frame = self.embeddedPlayerFrame;
    }
}
```